# How to use QuerySelector method in TestComplete

Tags: javascript, css-selectors, jscript, testcomplete, selectors-api

I don't know how the QuerySelector method works. I've seen examples on SmartBear help, but am having trouble on my application. I thought it worked the same way as the Find method.

For example, when I want to map a label, the Find method works like this:

```
warningLabel= webPagePanel.Find("objectIdentifier", "MainContent_NotificationText", 100, true);
```

When I try to map that same object using the QuerySelector method, it does not work:

```
warningLabel= webPagePanel.QuerySelector("#MainContent_NotificationText");
```

I try to use that QuerySelector warningLabel after the QuerySelector line above (For example,  `warningLabel.Click`), the test then fails and the log says "Object Required". So apparently it didnt find my object

What am I doing wrong? How exactly can I use the QuerySelector method for a simple mapping of label as shown above? The label in question has the below HTML.

```
INPUT "name=ctl00$MainContent$NotificationText" id="MainContent_NotificationText" type=hidden value="To save a partial filter set for this report, the required fields identified above must not be blank."
```

Comment: @ebyrob: This question is not about JavaScript's `document.querySelector`, it's about the `QuerySelector` function in TestComplete (a testing tool).

Comment: [`QuerySelector`](https://support.smartbear.com/viewarticle/72612/) method is defined only on web pages, e.g. `Sys.Browser().Page("http://example.com").QuerySelector(...)`. Is your `webPagePanel` object a page?

Comment: I got it to work. At first I was using the webPage object with QuerySelector. For some reason, I was unable to use QuerySelector with the entire page, e.g. webPage = Aliases.iexplore.IEWEBPAGE. Then webPage.QuerySelector did not work. So instead I used the panel like I showed above in my original post, and it works now, e.g. webPagePanel = Aliases.iexplore.IELOA.FIND("objectIdentifer","webPagePanel")...Then webPagePanel.QuerySelector worked.

Answer (score 1):

The object you try to find is invisible (input...type="**hidden**"...) and TestComplete does not show invisible objects in its object tree. If you just need to get the value of this hidden box, you can use the native version of the querySelector method instead:

```
  var warningLabel_Native = webPagePanel.contentDocument.querySelector("#MainContent_NotificationText");
  Log.Message(warningLabel_Native.value);
```

In this case, you will get the native object which does not have TestComplete-specific members like Click(), Find(), VisibleOnScreen, etc. However, all the native functionality will be available for you.